# Vertical align middle div inside div

Tags: html, css

Examining this HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <hr />
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can see that `footer` have position absolute and stay at the bottom of the page. `wrapper` will cover the remaining space and contain a `content` inside it. I want to vertical-align `content` without breaking the current layout. Do you have any suggestion?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/eEh8u/) is JSFiddle link. (Note: jsfiddle doesn't work as expected, there always a space beneath `footer`, this behavior doesn't occur when run the HTML file in browser).

Note: I don't want to use fixed height for `wrapper`, I want it covers all the remaining space, so please don't suggest me to use `line-height`

I tried the example [here](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/) but it doesn't seem to work

**NOTE** I want the layout easy to modify (like add a header or content at the top) without breaking it therefore I want to avoid using absolute position on `wrapper` and `content`

**NOTE 2** Sorry for not to clarify, actually, `content` doesn't have fixed size, its size depend on the content inside it, so the solution using `negative margin` doesn't work as I mentioned above

Comment: Will check back later, passed my bedtime!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using the following CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Use absolute positioning and then negative margins, since your content has well-defined
dimensions, this is relatively straightforward.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DgUV2/

For `.wrapper`, use the top, bottom, left and right offsets to stretch the div to the
full width and height, taking into account the 100px for the footer.

For `.content`, set top and left to 50%, the center point of the `.wrapper` and then adjust 
for the center of the `.content` div using negative margins.

Remember to zero out the margin for the `body` or else you might see 10px whitespace
depending on your browser.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, it works well. But is there anyway to avoid using `position: absolute` in bot `wrapper` and `container`? Because if I place something else on the top of the website, it will break the layout, so I want the layout flexible enough to easily extend without breaking the layout

Comment: Ah!!! now that is a different problem.  Would you consider using CSS table/table-cell?

Comment: Would you please show me the example or a reference link about table/table-cell solution?

Comment: If you add extra content above the wrapper, say a header, do you want the header, wrapper and footer to all be on a single page (no vertical scrolling)?

Comment: Yes, if I only add a header, but the scrolling would be fine if there were any more contents added

Comment: Let me sleep on this, will check back tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your effort. Good night, Sir! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `.content`

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Just 3 lines of code to **[vertical align](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)**

Comment: the code should be compatible in everything, a good developer should code like wise

Comment: So you wont be considering them?  it is left up to you, i said the fact, no more arguments please

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using [Method 1 from the example you linked](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/)

I added the following:

```
.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: green;
    /* THE BELOW WAS ADDED */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* BELOW ADDED TO REMOVE EXTRA SPACE AROUND EDGES */
    margin: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle of working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eEh8u/3/)

Comment: You are almost there, the `.wrapper` extends below the footer, probably not the desired effect.  See my answer, we are both using the same approach.

Comment: @MarcAudet Aaah I haven't seen your little twist on it before. Very nice! You win! ;)

Comment: Hey, we all win with SO! Learning is the key to fun!